# Can legit antivirus spying on user when ''accessibility-services'' in Tor are turned off and onion routing using?

Tags: onion-routing, deanonymization

I use one of the most popular antivirus program for Windows for months and some days ago I just noticed that it at least uses firewall and ''internet security and protection'' settings turned on and aren't explicitly represented.

Confidentiality policy of this program sounds for me like ''We always can take, store and share all information from you we want, include full URL`s of websites you've seen, your interests etc. way we want and as long as we want.''

*My specific question is can my activity in tor theoretically got viewed and stored due to fact I used onion routing and disabled ''accessibility-services'' https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/accessibility-services in Tor's settings. (I don't talk about viruses, adware or spyware itself) only about legit programs de jure registered in US*
Also I don't upload any addons in my browser too.

Thank for your for answers. I think it will be usefull for all users of ''antiviruses'' and ''internet security'' programs.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed a virus scanner, whose task it is to look for things that the manufacturer considers to be correct on your computer. Many virus scanners even report badly found things to the virus scanner manufacturer and check them again for you.

What the virus scanner manufacturer is actually looking for on your computer, probably only he knows himself. If they didn't just want to check for viruses, the software you installed, which you hope for the best, could also check for things and report them to the manufacturer or wherever else you don't like.

Any software, even a virus scanner, always poses a risk.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enable SSL protection - so there is no SSL inspection - then they can not track you *unless* you're installing the browser add-on from the antivirus manufacturer. *Keep in mind that some antiviruses are actually a spyware and rootkit - look at Kasperskiy's one for example: you can not disable SSL inspection at all in that software.*